# Change Select using ajax triggered on success

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My modal allows me to change the selected branch's data. Using ajax, I can get the data through my getter/get_location_info.php, and when I change selections, the following selects are populated.

My city select is populate from the list I fetch with php but the rest of the selects are populated with ajax through my getter. When I select a branch to update my modal city selection is correct and county selection is populated it is not selected and district, quarters are not populated.

My Script to populate selects:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#edit_city').change(function() {
            var cityId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'functions/getters/get_location_info.php',
                data: {
                    city_id: cityId
                },
                success: function(counties) {
                    $('#edit_county').html(counties);
                    $('#edit_district').html('<option value="0">Semt Seçiniz</option>');
                }
            });
        });

        $('#edit_county').change(function() {
            var countyId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'functions/getters/get_location_info.php',
                data: {
                    county_id: countyId
                },
                success: function(districts) {
                    $('#edit_district').html(districts);
                    $('#edit_quarter').html('<option value="0">Köy Mahalle Seçiniz</option>');
                }
            });
        });

        $('#edit_district').change(function() {
            var districtId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'functions/getters/get_location_info.php',
                data: {
                    district_id: districtId
                },
                success: function(quarters) {
                    $('#edit_quarter').html(quarters);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Script to get branch data and update modal input values:

```
<script>
    $('.btn-edit-branch').click(function() {
        var branchId = $(this).data('branch_id');
        var city_id, county_id, district_id, quarter_id;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/getters/get_location_info.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                branch_id_edit: branchId
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var branchInfo = JSON.parse(data);
                city_id = branchInfo.ref_city;
                county_id = branchInfo.ref_county;
                district_id = branchInfo.ref_district;
                quarter_id = branchInfo.ref_quarter;
                // Set branch information in modal form
                $('#edit_branch_id').val(branchInfo.id);
                $('#edit_branch_name').val(branchInfo.branch_name);
                $('#edit_address').val(branchInfo.address);
                $('#edit_branch_mail').val(branchInfo.email);
                $('#edit_branch_phone').val(branchInfo.phone);
                $('#edit_city').val(city_id).trigger('change');
                $('#edit_county').val(county_id).trigger('change');
                $('#edit_district').val(district_id).trigger('change');
                $('#edit_quarter').val(quarter_id).trigger('change');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Veriler çekilirken bir hata oluştu');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you and Appreciate your helps in advance

Comment: This seems backwards. A county contains cities, so when you select a county it should populate the city dropdown with the list of cities in that county.

Comment: Actually population order goes like this on my system city->county->district->quarter so the order is correct I assume ofcourse if I didn't misunderstand what you said

Comment: OK, I guess it's just a language issue. In the US it's country->state->county->city->neighborhood.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I guess so, maybe I should rename them later :)

Comment: The problem you're having is that `.trigger('change')` will start another AJAX call that will populate the next dropdown asynchronously. But you're not waiting for that asynchronous update before you set the value of the next dropdown. Fixing this will be complicated

Comment: Maybe you could write an API method that takes all the location info and returns the contents of all the dropdowns at once.

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure how I can do that but I guess it worths looking into it

Comment: Another alternative would be to extract the code that populates dropdowns from AJAX into named functions. Then you can rewrite this using `await` to do these sequentially, rather than using `.trigger("change")`

Comment: @Barmar Tried that, It didn't work or I have done it wrong.